# Can Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 connect to SQL Server 2019 and perform DML without issue?

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, sql-server-2019, java, jdbc

The [SQL version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-version-compatibility) BOL article advises that the minimum compatible JDBC driver version for SQL Server 2019 is 7.4.

Can an older JDBC driver still connect to SQL Server 2019? Or can only the driver versions listed as compatible connect to the specified SQL Server versions?

Comment: Have you tried it?...

Comment: No, I get your point. But there is always a chance that I make a mistake in the implementation of my test which invalidates the result.

Comment: But that's what testing is for - make a few tests up and give it a try.

Comment: *'there is always a chance that I make a mistake in the implementation'* ... Welcome to programming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft and my testing have confirmed that JDBC drivers not marked as compatible in the [SQL version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-version-compatibility) matrix might connect to a non compatible version of SQL Server and continue to work without issue.

However, there is no guarantee that all functionality detailed in the [Driver feature support matrix for Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/driver-feature-matrix?view=sql-server-ver15) is supported. They also only test the  driver versions marked as compatible against the stated version of SQL Server.

JDBC version 4.0 was not specifically tested.